# Почему в jquery не могу пройти по каждому элементу html?

Tags: html, jquery

Прохожу циклом по каждому элементу, но почему то после добавления .is пишет ошибку:TypeError: j.is is not a function

[ссылка на код](https://jsfiddle.net/8of6djuL/4/):

```
$('input[name=chсl]').click(function () {
for(var i=0;i<$('input[name=chсl]').length;i++)
 {
  var j = $('input[name=chсl]')[i]
    alert(j.is(':checked') + " " + $('.ch-checkbox')[i].find('.count'));
  }
});
```

Comment: `$('input[name=chсl]')[i]` - вернет HTMLElement, в то время как `is` - это метод jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вариант по проще.

Да и проверять "checked" лучше через [.prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
$('input[name="chсl"]').each(function(i){
  let isCheck = $(this).prop('checked');
  console.info('input['+i+'] checked? - '+isCheck);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ch-corr-loci">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chсl" checked>
  <label class="ch-checkbox">1: <span class="count">14</span></label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="chсl">
  <label class="ch-checkbox">2: <span class="count">8</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @chilo5432, не за что. Если моё решение помогло, поставьте галочку как "правильный ответ")

Comment: я хотел. Но там минуту попросили подождать. А щас поставил

Comment: @chilo5432, ааа, ясно, теперь спасибо Вам)